# Unit test in Go for function which used chrono scheduling

Tags: go, time, microservices, scheduled-tasks

`

```
func (s *svc) MaintainLog() {
      taskScheduler := chrono.NewDefaultTaskScheduler()
      task, err := taskScheduler.ScheduleAtFixedRate(func(ctx context.Context) {
         s.logger.Info("cleaning logs exceeded ttl")
         err := s.dao.MaintainTtlLogs(ctx)
         if err != nil {
            s.logger.Error("error in maintaining logs in db  : ", err)
         }
      }, 24*time.Hour)

      if err == nil {
         log.Print("Task has been scheduled successfully.")
      } else {
         task.Cancel()
      }
   

}
```

`

This is function for which i have to write unit test.
how this can be done

I tried by channel thing but not getting actually what to do and how